# MySQL view turns SUM of an INT column into a decimal type

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models

I have a MySQL view like this:

```
VIEW `qty_sold_view` AS
    SELECT 
        `t2`.`upc` AS `upc`, SUM(`t2`.`qty`) AS `qty_sold`
    FROM
        (`inventory_orders` `t1`
        JOIN `inventory_sales` `t2` ON ((`t2`.`order_id` = `t1`.`id`)))
    WHERE
        (`t1`.`date_placed` > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 42 DAY))
    GROUP BY `t2`.`upc`
```

And I run a query for this view using a Django raw query:

```
sql = 'SELECT `upc`, `qty_sold` FROM `qty_sold_view` WHERE `upc` = 1001 OR `upc`= 1002 ...'
with connection.cursor() as con:
    con.execute(sql)
```

Note that I have a Django model for both the `inventory_orders` table and `inventory_sales` table, but not the view itself.

The results from this query look like this:

```
((1001, Decimal('1')), (1002, Decimal('4')), ...)
```

Both the `qty` column and `upc` column of `inventory_sales` is type INT, so I don't understand why the data is returned as `Decimal`.

The problem is that when I try to `json.dumps` the results of this query, I get this:

> TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable

I could address this issue using various answers I found online to actually json serialize decimals, but it seems silly to do that when they shouldn't be decimals in the first place.

What can I do to force MySQL to treat them as INTs?

Comment: Just curious - why do you have a view?

Comment: No good reason now that I think about it xD.  Would there be a performance difference between running `SELECT * FROM view` and running the view as a query?

Comment: Views in MySQL have remarkably limited access to their underlying indexes, so performance is likely to improved by dispensing with the view.

Comment: Good to know.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/), you are always supposed to use `FORMAT` when using the `SUM` function.

Changing the view to:

```
VIEW `qty_sold_view` AS
SELECT 
    `t2`.`upc` AS `upc`, FORMAT(SUM(`t2`.`qty`), 0) AS `qty_sold`
FROM
    (`inventory_orders` `t1`
    JOIN `inventory_sales` `t2` ON ((`t2`.`order_id` = `t1`.`id`)))
WHERE
    (`t1`.`date_placed` > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 42 DAY))
GROUP BY `t2`.`upc`
```

Fixed it for me.